# How to know when and where to transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, hessian-matrix

I was reading a great blog post about [Fisher Information](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2018/03/11/fisher-information/) and I cam upon the part where the Fisher matrix is defined as the variance of the score...

$$
\begin{aligned}
Var[x] = \mathbb{E}[x^2] - \mathbb{E}[x]^2 \implies \mathbb{E}[\nabla \log p(x|\theta) \nabla \log p(x|\theta)^\top] - 0
\end{aligned}
$$

I couldn't explain something basic to myself while reading this. Why is the generalization of multiplication done by the operation $AA^\top$ in the expectation? Why couldn't it be $A^\top A$ or even $AA$?

Comment: The wikipedia could be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable#Covariance_and_cross-covariance

Comment: as far as I can tell, the wikipedia article just gives more examples of calculating the variance, it still does nothing to gain any intuition about why it is done this way instead of the other two ways that I mention in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here $\nabla\log p(x\mid\theta)$ is a vector but NOT a matrix. When calculating the variance-covariance matrix, only vectors are involved. Of course we cannot multiply a vector by itself.

In multivariate case, a random vector is defined as ${\bf X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^T$, where $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are all random variables, though not necessarily independent. If you take ${\bf X}^T{\bf X}$, you get only **a scalar**. All the information are lost.

Then why ${\bf X}{\bf X^T}$ works? For $i,j=1,\ldots,n$, we have
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(X_i)&=\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_i^2)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_i)^2, \\
\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)&=\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_iX_j)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_i)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_j). 
\end{align*}
Those two holds generally without any special assumption. Now let us take a look at ${\bf X}{\bf X^T}$:
$${\bf X}{\bf X^T}=\begin{bmatrix} 
X_1^2 & X_1X_2 & \cdots & X_1X_n \\
X_2X_1 & X_2^2 & \cdots & X_2X_n \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
X_nX_1 & X_nX_2 & \cdots & X_n^2
\end{bmatrix}, $$
so
$$\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X}{\bf X^T})=\begin{bmatrix} 
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1^2) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1X_n) \\
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2X_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2^2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2X_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_nX_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_nX_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n^2)
\end{bmatrix}.$$
On the other hand,
$$\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X})=\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)
\end{bmatrix}^T,$$
thus
$$\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X})\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X})^T=\begin{bmatrix} 
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1)^2 & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1X_n) \\
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)^2 & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)^2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The difference between these two matrix is
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X}{\bf X^T})-\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X})\operatorname{\Bbb E}({\bf X})^T \\
&=\begin{bmatrix} 
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1)^2-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1)^2 & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1X_n)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1X_n) \\
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2X_1)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2^2)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)^2 & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2X_n)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_nX_1)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_1) & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_nX_2)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n^2)-\operatorname{\Bbb E}(X_n)^2
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\operatorname{Var}(X_1) & \operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_n) \\
\operatorname{Cov}(X_2,X_1) & \operatorname{Var}(X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{Cov}(X_2,X_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
\operatorname{Cov}(X_n,X_1) & \operatorname{Cov}(X_n,X_2) & \cdots & \operatorname{Var}(X_n)
\end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align*}
This symmetric matrix preserves all the information.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer